# Python ошибка подключения драйвера

Tags: python, sql, база-данных

```
import pypyodbc

mySQLServer = "PCC\SQLEXPRESS
myDatabase = "northwind"

connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver=(SQL Server);'
                          'Server=' + mySQLServer + ';'
                          'Database=' + myDatabase + ';')
cursor = connection.cursor()
mySQLQuery = ("""

            SELECT CompanyName, ContactName, Country
            FROM [Northwind].[dbo].[Customers]
            WHERE country = 'USA'
""")

cursor.execute(mySQLQuery)
results = cursor.fetchall()

print(results)

connection.close()
```

**Ошибки:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "B:/Program Files/pyCharm/new1/SQLServer.py", line 10, in <module>
'Database=' + myDatabase + ';')

File "B:\Program Files\python\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 2454, in __init__
self.connect(connectString, autocommit, ansi, timeout, unicode_results, readonly)
File "B:\Program Files\python\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 2507, in connect
check_success(self, ret)
File "B:\Program Files\python\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 1009, in check_success
ctrl_err(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, ODBC_obj.dbc_h, ret, ODBC_obj.ansi)
File "B:\Program Files\python\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 985, in ctrl_err
raise Error(state,err_text)
pypyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][Диспетчер драйверов ODBC] Источник данных не найден и не указан драйвер, используемый по умолчанию')
```

Слышал, что для моей версии **Python** надо вставлять драйвер в **odbcad32.exe** в **SysWOW64**, но как пошагово это сделать? (например, в какую именно вкладку ставить и прочее, если конечно остальная часть кода правильная)

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте для начала избавиться от скобок в mySQLQuery

```
import pypyodbc

mySQLServer = "PCC\SQLEXPRESS
myDatabase = "northwind"

connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver=(SQL Server);'
                          'Server=' + mySQLServer + ';'
                          'Database=' + myDatabase + ';')
cursor = connection.cursor()
mySQLQuery = """
            SELECT CompanyName, ContactName, Country
            FROM [Northwind].[dbo].[Customers]
            WHERE country = 'USA'
"""

cursor.execute(mySQLQuery)
results = cursor.fetchall()

print(results)

connection.close()
```

пример для Vertica

```
import pypyodbc

ds=pypyodbc.dataSources()
db = pypyodbc.connect("DSN=HPVertica")
cursor = db.cursor()
sql="SELECT count(*) from WAREHOUSE.ALL_EVENTS"
cursor.execute(sql)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print (row)
```

Comment: mySQLQuery = ("""

                SELECT CompanyName, ContactName, Country
                FROM dbo.Customers
                WHERE country = 'USA'
""")

Избавился от скобок. Но как быть с ошибками? Их количество не изменилось

Comment: плюс еще не сразу заметил, что вы забыли закрыть кавычки mySQLServer = "PCC\SQLEXPRESS"

Comment: Да, тут почему-то она стерлась, но в оригинальном коде она есть. Но спасибо так или иначе.

Comment: А как работать то конкретно с драйвером? как его подключить в винде и в коде?

Comment: используете администрирование windows и прописываете там DSN и далее на него ссылаетесь уже в коде